# Need to return objects containing the key which referred from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return the objects which has key of `submittedDate`. But if i am trying with `find()` It's returning only the first object. And for map it's returning undefined for object not having submittedDate key. Please find my code with data and also the result I want. thanks in advance.

```js
    const data = [
        {   
            id: '1',
            name: 'Tully Stark',
            submittedData:'mmmmm'
        },
        {
            id:'2',
            name: 'Nalani Romanova',
        },
         {
            id:'3',
            name: 'Nalani Romanova',
            submittedData:'mmmmm'
        }
    ]  
    
    const submitDate = data.find(item => item.submittedData)
    
    console.log(submitDate)
```

data to return

```js
const returnData = [
    {   
        id: '1',
        name: 'Tully Stark',
        submittedData:'mmmmm'
    },
     {
        id:'3',
        name: 'Nalani Romanova',
        submittedData:'mmmmm'
    }
]
```

Comment: [_"The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). You want [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) by definition only returns the first matching object.

> **`Array.prototype.find()`**
> The `find()` method returns the value of the **first** element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned.

You need to use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const submitDate = data.filter(item => item.submittedData)
```

---

```js
const data = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Tully Stark',
    submittedData: 'mmmmm'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Nalani Romanova',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Nalani Romanova',
    submittedData: 'mmmmm'
  }
]

const submitDate = data.filter(item => item.submittedData)

console.log(submitDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), this will return all matching items.

```js
const data = [ { id: '1', name: 'Tully Stark', submittedData:'mmmmm' }, { id:'2', name: 'Nalani Romanova', }, { id:'3', name: 'Nalani Romanova', submittedData:'mmmmm' } ]

const submitDate = data.filter(item => item.submittedData)
console.log(submitDate)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```